# Split Mysql table on date column and store result in different tables with dynamic name

Tags: mysql, talend

My job looks like the first image where I am trying to read a Mysql table,
and split the table based on the FROM_DATE field. The steps in the job are as follows :

1. Use tMap to create a column StringFromDate -> TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd",row1.FROM_DATE)
2. Connect tMapOutput to tFlowToIterate
3. Connect tFlowToIterate to tFixedFlowInput. The tFixedFlowInput component configuration is shown in the second image below
4. Connect tFixedFlowInput to tLogRow
5. Connect tLogRow to tMysqlOutput. The tMysqlOutput component setting is as shown in the third image.

The problem is that the tables are generating with only 1 row of data. When I try to collect the data in a csv file, this setting works fine with an append option in tFileOutputDelimited.

Please, immediate help required.

[image: Job Design]

[image: tFixedFlowInput Component]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problm is caused by the `tMysqlOutput` setting `drop table if exists and create`, which effectively recreates your table at each iteration. Thus the one line you end up with in your table is the one corresponding to the last iteration.
Try with the setting `create table if not exists`.
Also, based on your followup question, you need to add `OnComponentOk -- tMysqlCommit` (uncheck close connection) after your `tMysqlOutput` in order to commit the inserts.

Comment: I tried using "create table if not exists" and "Insert" as Action on data. This is  creating another problem. Some empty tables are being created and the total number of rows from all the tables are lesser than the table that was split.

Comment: do you have autocommit enabled on your tMysqlConnection (advanced settings)? If not, then you should add OnComponentOk -- tMysqlCommit after your tMysqlOutput

Comment: Both the solutions solved the problem of empty tables, I also had to uncheck "Close Connection" tMySqlCommit, but the total number of rows from all the tables is 1 more than the actual number of rows. I cant understand why there is 1 extra row. I am using "SELECT * FROM  facility_monthly ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20" in tMySqlInput to generate 20 rows from my table but the total count of the number of rows from the split tables are 21.

Comment: I don't see how that could be.. could you look at the data and see which row  that is being added ? maybe do a `select date, count(*) from table group by date` on your source table to get the number of expected rows in each resulting table, and compare that with the actual number of rows in each table.

Comment: My actual table has 2 lakh rows, therefore to design the job, I am generating 20 random rows each time to check the output and it is generating one extra row.

Comment: I'm glad :) if my answer was the what got it working, please consider accepting it. Regards